# Nginx alias parent dir redirecting weirdly and auth not covering site

Tags: nginx

I have two problems with Nginx I am hoping someone could help me with.

I have setup an aliased directory in my site called /wordpress/ and made it point to a file outside of my webroot now that's all working fine and dandy until I try and browse the parent directory: /wordpress. It seems to want to redirect to *.x.co.uk (where x represents my domain name). Config to follow.

My other problem is that my Auth is not covering more than the root directory / despite being in the / caluse to catch anything that's not /wordpress/ which is confusing me again. So I have to auth if I go to / but if I go /video I can get into my site without auth at all.

I am a bit new to Nginx so it's prolly something stupid that I got confused on while reading the Wiki.

Anyone have any ideas? Here is my config for your viewing pleasure:

```
server {
        listen          80;
        server_name     _;
       root            /server_ws/the_stage/htdocs;
        access_log      /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log       /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        error_page 404 /error/notfound;

        location /wordpress/ {
                alias /server_ws/wordpress/;
#               try_files $uri $uri/;
        }

   location ~* ^/wordpress/(.+).(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|xml)$ {
           alias            /server_ws/wordpress/$1.$2;
           access_log      off;
           expires         30d;
   }

        location / {
                auth_basic "Restricted";
                auth_basic_user_file /etc/apache2/passwords;

                index   index.php;

                if ($host = 'x.co.uk') {
                        rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://www.x.co.uk/$1 permanent;
                }

                if (-f $request_filename) {
                        break;
                }

                if (!-e $request_filename) {
                        rewrite . /index.php last;
                }

                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

    location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|xml)$ {
            root            /server_ws/the_stage/htdocs;
            access_log      off;
            expires         30d;
    }

}
```

Here are some log entries for the auth. You can see in this one were a bot tried to access my robots.txt and fails due to auth:

```
2012/05/20 11:54:10 [error] 12059#0: *2008 no user/password was provided for basic authentication, client: 108.162.215.232, server: _, request: "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.0", host: "www.x.co.uk"
```

But then I go to /video on my site and I get no errors but I get an access log of:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [20/May/2012:12:51:35 +0000] "GET /video?cat=gaming&sort=upload_date HTTP/1.1" 301 185 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
```

Here is the lastest log for /wordpress access:

```
xxx.xxx.xx.xxx - - [20/May/2012:13:01:08 +0000] "GET /wordpress HTTP/1.1" 301 185 "-" "Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; U; Edition Campaign 21; en) Presto/2.10.229 Version/11.64"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First question solution is changing `location /wordpress/` block to that:

```
location /wordpress {
    alias /server_ws/wordpress/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

And please fix www rewrite, instead of if ([which is evil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil)) add this block:

```
server {
    server_name x.co.uk;
    return 301 $scheme://www.x.co.uk$request_uri;
}
```

And, by the way, delete `listen 80` from first server block, it's [implemented by default](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen).

UPD: `rewrite` [➡](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Taxing_Rewrites) `return`.

Comment: Thanks but it didnt work, however what is interesting is that firefoxz redirects to *.x.co.uk/wordpress/ while chrome and the others redirect to _/wordpress/ but that's weird cos the Wiki says the server name shouldn't play like that. I have added ther logs for the auth and also there is nothing in the logs for /wordpress except the log I've posted abovce as well, not sure if it's my logging level or not...

Comment: Ok I've been able to solve the second problem it turns out that part of my config said "if file does not exist rewrite to index.php" it must have caused some kinda of flaw in the auth but the auth now covers the entire site except /wordpress which is correct, but that wordpress is still rewrite weirdly. I take sever name out and it rewrites to ip-xx-xx-xx/wordpress it's weird that its even trying to redirect in the first place though :S

Comment: Hmm I spoke too soon with that solution. It works on x.co.uk but not www.x.co.uk even when I change the server name to include or variations. What do you mean by what's wrong?

Comment: What's weird is that it's redirecting the same as x.co.uk (the www. that is) but it's just not getting auth.....this is really confusing :S

Comment: Fixed a bit, check. I presume wordpress is real wordpress isntallation with php handled somewhere.

Comment: Awesome mate that's fixed a few confusions in my config and got it working much better :) I took out the try_files in the wordpress bit cos that party of the site is directory based anyway and even though I want to allow people to browse files I weant 403 on the directories themselves and it seemed to work just as good without the try files. I also found my dns was act badly when I refreshed my client cache (lol) so it appears it was actually my computers cache that was making half teh trouble. But anyway thanks :D